# I want to get the real path of a file in java by using the request method getRealPath()but it is deprecated now i want an alternate to it

Tags: java, servlets

I want to get the real path of a file in java by using the request method getRealPath()but it is deprecated now i want an alternate to it i tried get servletcontext but it is not returning the whole path

in jsp page when i m using application.getRealPath("/") it is giving whole path as D:/.....

but in java servlet code i m not getting this method working so i want a perfect httprequest method which will be returning whole path of the application.

please suggest me a perfect method with example if possible

Answer (score 6):

`request.getServletContext().getRealPath(..)` (or if you are within a servlet, just call `getServletContext().getRealPath(..)`

Comment: i am using struts 1 in this i had tried this earlier request.getServletContext is not defined giving error

Answer (score -1):

try this one request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");